# Performing a New Code Review on a Brand New Git Repository

Tags: git, code-collaborator

I want to perform a code review on a brand new repository.  This means I want all code to be reviewed not just a portion of it.  However, when I enter:

```
 ccollab addgitdiffs 1234 0000..HEAD
```

I get:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '0000..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
No files to review!
```

How do you review a brand new git repository?  I tried to upload a tar of the code but it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Any-way-to-get-complete-diff-up-to-a-tag-td5013322.html). It looks like there's a specific sha1 for an empty tree that's always the same (all empty trees being equal): 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904

Comment: I get error: Object 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 is a tree, not a commit

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Code Collaborator, so I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for this new repository came from another location.  I did a review from the first changeset to the last.  That seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I use code collaborator and you can use the "empty" git commit for this:

```
ccollab addgitdiffs new 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904..HEAD
```